# NOT IN SQL query not working

Tags: mysql

This is a question from Hacker Rank.

> Let NUM be the number of CITY entries in STATION table, and NUMunique
>   be the number of unique cities. Query the value of NUM−NUMunique from
>   STATION.

This is the query that I've written.

```
SELECT COUNT(CITY) FROM STATION WHERE CITY NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) FROM STATION);
```

This is yielding the wrong answer. Any idea what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Show the table structure and some test data. Show the result you get and explain why do you think it is *"the wrong answer"*. Show the right answer. Read [ask].

Comment: Of course it produces the wrong answer. The inner `SELECT COUNT(...)` produces a number. `WHERE CITY NOT IN (SELECT COUNT(...))` is like comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: I think you are missing the fact the correct answer is `Total Num of Cities - Num of Unique Cities` Thats not what your query is doing

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's precisely the query I'm trying to write.

Comment: Well in that case you have to count cities, count unique cities and then take one from the other. You are `counting cities where city not in 100` for example. Which makes no sence and is not what you are trying to do

Comment: Try writing two separate queries. Then subtract `NUMunique` from `NUM`. For example, `SELECT NUM = COUNT(CITY) FROM STATION;` ... figure the query for the second half, and just subtract the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DISTINCT keyword inside a COUNT() to get your answer in one simple query

```
SELECT COUNT(CITY) - COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) as the_answer FROM STATION;
```

Comment: I did `SELECT((SELECT COUNT(CITY) FROM STATION) - (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) FROM STATION));` which worked. Ofcourse you've a more elegant solution but I'm new to SQL.